# Как разделить сущности на разные таблицы в наследование

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Имеется следующие классы:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : User
{
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
public class Manager : User
{
    public string Departament { get; set; }
}
```

EF core создаёт общую таблицу для трёх сущности.(User) При этом, когда я создаю одинаковые индексы в разных сущности (в Employee и Manager ), EF core выдает ошибку дублирование индексов в таблице User. Можно ли разделить сущности в разных таблицах? Может я не достаточно хорошо искал решение или просто не понял. Покажите это простым примером пожалуйста

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph TPH - Table per Hierarchy. Как мне кажется индекс (Id) должен быть уникален для всей таблицы, т.е. не повторяться вне зависимости от сущности.

Comment: использовать атрибут `[Table("TableName")]` пробовали? мне кажется поможет

Comment: @tCode, не получилось. Всё равно создаёт одну таблицу

Comment: @XelaNimed ваш пример на EF , а не на EF core

Comment: Это не пример, это подход: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/4.1.php

Comment: @XelaNimed Тут не показано как разделить таблицы

Comment: Если Вам нужно разделить на таблицы, то наследование не подойдёт. В этом случае уберите наследование и добавляйте ссылку на UserId в Employee и Manager.

Comment: ну кстати да, делаете 3 сущности без наследования и там где нужны связи вставляете уже `public virtual User User { get;set; }` например